# Dúvida sobre sites com https

Tags: seo, ssl, https

Como que eu faria pra deixar meu site com https ?

Uso uma hospedagem gratuita na infinityFree e tentei mexer com o SSL do CPanel mas não tive nenhum sucesso.

Comment: Pesquise aqui: https://letsencrypt.org/ e aqui https://www.cloudflare.com/br/ssl/

Comment: Consegui pelo cloudflare obg.

Comment: Consegui com  o popio suporte paguei o serviço o suporte foi la e adicionou para mim